# Delete Duplicates from large mysql Address DB

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I know, deleting duplicates from mysql is often discussed here. But none of the solution work fine within my case.

So, I have a DB with Address Data nearly like this:

```
ID; Anrede; Vorname; Nachname; Strasse; Hausnummer; PLZ; Ort; Nummer_Art; Vorwahl; Rufnummer
```

ID is primary Key and unique.

And i have entrys for example like this:

```
1;Herr;Michael;Müller;Testweg;1;55555;Testhausen;Mobile;012345;67890
2;Herr;Michael;Müller;Testweg;1;55555;Testhausen;Fixed;045678;877656
```

The different PhoneNumber are not the problem, because they are not relevant for me. So i just want to delete the duplicates in Lastname, Street and Zipcode. In that case ID 1 or ID 2. Which one of both doesn't matter.

I tried it actually like this with delete:

```
DELETE db 

FROM Import_Daten db, 
     Import_Daten dbl 

WHERE db.id > dbl.id AND 
      db.Lastname = dbl.Lastname AND 
      db.Strasse = dbl.Strasse AND 
      db.PLZ = dbl.PLZ;
```

And insert into a copy table:

```
INSERT INTO Import_Daten_1

SELECT MIN(db.id),
       db.Anrede, 
       db.Firstname, 
       db.Lastname, 
       db.Branche, 
       db.Strasse, 
       db.Hausnummer, 
       db.Ortsteil, 
       db.Land, 
       db.PLZ, 
       db.Ort, 
       db.Kontaktart, 
       db.Vorwahl, 
       db.Durchwahl

 FROM Import_Daten db, 
      Import_Daten dbl

 WHERE db.lastname = dbl.lastname AND
       db.Strasse = dbl.Strasse And 
       db.PLZ = dbl.PLZ;
```

The complete table contains over 10Mio rows. The size is actually my problem. The mysql runs on a MAMP Server on a Macbook with  1,5GHZ  and 4GB RAM. So not really fast. SQL Statements run in a phpmyadmin. Actually i have no other system possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new column e.g. `uq` and make it `UNIQUE`.

```
ALTER TABLE Import_Daten 
ADD COLUMN `uq` BINARY(16) NULL,
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `uq_UNIQUE` (`uq` ASC);
```

When this is done you can execute an `UPDATE` query like this

```
UPDATE IGNORE Import_Daten 
SET 
    uq = UNHEX(
           MD5(
             CONCAT(
               Import_Daten.Lastname,
               Import_Daten.Street,
               Import_Daten.Zipcode
             )
           )
         )
WHERE
    uq IS NULL;
```

Once all entries are updated and the query is executed again, all duplicates will have the `uq` field with a value=`NULL` and can be removed.

The result then is:

`0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1062 Duplicate entry...`

For newly added rows always create the `uq` hash and and consider using this as the primary key once all entries are unique.

Comment: to prevent inserting duplicates we can add a unique index on ( Lastname, Strasse, PLZ ) set of fields.

Comment: Applying this solution first time will delete all duplicate records. It won't leave one copy of duplicate record.

Comment: @olegsv no it keeps all uq fields NULL which are duplicates... so the records are kept and can be removed manually after update query above was finally executed... ``ADD COLUMN `uq` BINARY(16) NULL`` and ``ADD UNIQUE INDEX `uq_UNIQUE` (`uq` ASC);``

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) that will each time select a different chunk of data (for example by `rownumber` between two values) and delete only from that range. This way you will slowly bit by bit delete your duplicates

Comment: Thanks. I have no experience with stored procedures. I'll have a look at this. But if j just "clean" a range within row numbers and the Data isn't sorted it can't work, or?

Comment: @Chrisko - Added a link to some documentation

Answer (score 1):

A more effective two table solution can look like following. 
We can store only the data we really need to delete and only the fields that contain duplicate information.
Let's assume we are looking for duplicate data in Lastname , Branche, Haushummer fields.

Create table to hold the duplicate data

`DROP TABLE data_to_delete;`

Populate the table with data we need to delete ( I assume all fields have VARCHAR(255) type )

`CREATE TABLE data_to_delete ( 
    id BIGINT COMMENT 'this field will contain ID of row that we will not delete',
    cnt INT, 
    Lastname VARCHAR(255), 
    Branche VARCHAR(255), 
    Hausnummer VARCHAR(255) 
) AS SELECT 
    min(t1.id) AS id,
    count(*) AS cnt, 
    t1.Lastname, 
    t1.Branche, 
    t1.Hausnummer
FROM Import_Daten AS t1 
GROUP BY t1.Lastname, t1.Branche, t1.Hausnummer 
HAVING count(*)>1 ;`

Now let's delete duplicate data and leave only one record of all duplicate sets

`DELETE Import_Daten 
    FROM Import_Daten LEFT JOIN data_to_delete 
    ON Import_Daten.Lastname=data_to_delete.Lastname 
    AND Import_Daten.Branche=data_to_delete.Branche
    AND Import_Daten.Hausnummer = data_to_delete.Hausnummer 
WHERE Import_Daten.id != data_to_delete.id;`

`DROP TABLE data_to_delete;`

Comment: Thanks. That also works. But the version from Bernhard is much faster and better for further imports.

Comment: @Chrisko I agree it's faster. To prevent inserting duplicate records you can use unique index. In addition I'm afraid applying this solution on existing data you will delete ALL duplicate records and won't leave one copy of a duplicate series.